# Count groups of consecutive values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe with 0 and 1 and I would like to count groups of 1s (don't mind the 0s) with a **Pandas** solution (not itertools, not python iteration).

Other SO posts suggest methods based on `shift()`/`diff()`/`cumsum()` which seems not to work when the leading sequence in the dataframe starts with 0.

```py
df = pandas.Series([0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1]) # should give 4
df = pandas.Series([1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1])     # should also give 4
df = pandas.Series([1,1,1,1,1,0,1])             # should give 2
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only have 0/1, you can use:

```
s = pd.Series([0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1])

count = s.diff().fillna(s).eq(1).sum()
```

output: `4` (`4` and `2` for the other two)

Then `fillna` ensures that Series starting with `1` will be counted

##### faster alternative

use the diff, count the 1 and correct the result with the first item:

```
count = s.diff().eq(1).sum()+(s.iloc[0]==1)
```

comparison of different pandas approaches:

[image]

Comment: For posterity and those who only check the accepted answer : the Shubham Sharma's answer is also very interesting :)

Comment: Undoubtedly, @Shubham always has nice answers ;)

Answer (score 3):

Let us identify the diffrent groups of 1's using `cumsum`, then use `nunique` to count the number of unique groups

```
m = df.eq(0)
m.cumsum()[~m].nunique()
```

Result

```
case 1: 4
case 2: 4
case 3: 2
```

Comment: nice, but the combination of `cumsum`/slicing/`nunique` is slow on large data. (for example 5 times slower than diff/fillna on 10M items), should be similar on small lists ;)

Comment: This one is nice :) I accepted the other one because I'm still not sure wether I'll have large data or not.

Comment: @Pierre No problem. happy coding ~